# Android Studio with OpenCV error dlopen failed: library "libopencv_java3415.so" not found

Tags: android, opencv

The detailed error when I tried with OpenCV3 is:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libopencv_java3415.so" not found
```

I have been struggling with this error. I have tried copying the content of the /libs folder to jnilibs directory even with different versions of OpenCV (v4 and v3) but no success at all. Any help is very much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a (dumb) way to deal with this error. I renamed the "libopencv_java3.so" to "libopencv_java3415.so" and it worked. But this is very strange...